# Errors while validating

Tags: html

I'm new to web development and I'm getting two errors when I validate with https://validator.w3.org. My code is below. Any advice would be great! Thanks everyone!

One is: "Stray end tag head.
From line 9, column 1; to line 9, column 7
ght="80">↩↩

Second is: "Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.
From line 10, column 1; to line 10, column 6 >↩↩↩

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<img src="images/town_hall_logo.gif" alt="Town Hall" height="80">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h2>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</h2>
    <h3>Celebrating our 75<sup>th</sup> Year</h3>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When I ran this through the validator, it said that the DOCTYPE line was missing.  Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line.

2) You have an `<img>` tag between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags.  That should be moved into the body.

When I made these two changes, validation was successful.

Comment: Sorry I already had the <!doctype html>, I just didn't add it to my original question. Glad to say though, the 2nd change is what gave me a successful validation and kept the structure on my page. Thanks for the help Phil!